# ¿Cómo valido acceso según tipo de usuario?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, formularios, webforms

Tengo la tabla usuario: nombre, alias,clave, id_tipousuario y tipo usuario: id_tipousuario en sqlserver y un login en Asp.net webforms.
¿Cómo hago para validar y bloquear acceso a campos de un menú hecho con bootstrap?

Perdón por preguntar muchas cosas, pero para webforms es difícil encontrar material. Aquí una parte del código:

```
<div class="wrapper row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
        <aside class="left-side sidebar-offcanvas">
            <section class="sidebar">
                <div class="user-panel">
                    <div class="pull-left image">
                        <img src="img/descarga.png" class="img-circle" alt="User Image" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-left info">
                        <p>Bienvenido</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="PanelGeneral.aspx">
                            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                            <span>Panel General</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="fmrVentas.aspx">
                            <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                            <span>Ventas</span>
                         </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="fmrCompras.aspx">
                            <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                            <span>Compras</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

Comment: Por favor, comparte tu código para que algún compañero pueda ayudarte de la mejor manera posible.

Comment: conoces ado.net para ejecutar un select? o como accedes a los registros de la db

Comment: como armas el menu bootstrap en el aspx ? digo lo defines con puro html fijo o lo armas dinamicamente desde codigo c# en el aspx.cs

Comment: Dependerá de como crees tu menú, pienso que lo deberías hacer dinámico. Para ello, desde tu bd  contar con una tabla permisos y tareas. Ejemplo: en la tabla permisos (id, nombreWebform, urlWebForm, seccion), tabla (id, idtablapermisos, nombreTarea, activo)

Comment: Estoy trabajando la bd con una instriuccion sqlconnection y el menu lo saque de un template y esta  fijo con html y las clases de bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Debe ser manejado por tabla de *rol*, y cada usuario debe contar con uno de ellos. De acuerdo al *rol* se puede otorgar o no acceso al menú, este menú debe estar en la base de datos con el fin de que exista una tabla intermedia por ejemplo *RolePages*. De esta forma se puede parametrizar a qué páginas tendrá acceso el usuario según su *rol*.